# How can I copy nodes from one xml file to another, using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I am trying to do the following:

I have the following xml_1 file, which I generated.

```
<document>
   <TITLE>Computer Parts</TITLE>
   <header>
      <ITEM>Motherboard</ITEM>
      <MANUFACTURER>ASUS</MANUFACTURER>
      <MODEL>P3B-F</MODEL>
      <COST> 123.00</COST>
   </header>
   <part1>
      <ITEM>Video Card</ITEM>
      <MANUFACTURER>ATI</MANUFACTURER>
      <MODEL>All-in-Wonder Pro</MODEL>
      <COST> 160.00</COST>
   </part1>
   .....
   <part5>
   </part5>
 {HERE I WANT TO ADD NODES FROM OTHER XML FILES}
</document>
```

Because I am trying to generate a big xml file, I prefer to generate them in pieces and combine them in the end.
In that way I have cleaner and more readable code.

In the end I want to copy the xml files (xml_2,xml_3,etc) in sequence in the **xml_1** file. 
So, lets say that I have another xml_2 file like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <part6>
   </part6>
    ...
   <part10>
   </part10>
```

And so on.. I can have xml_3 .. xml_n.

**My question is:**
Is it possible using Nokogiri in a ruby file to copy the nodes of one xml file to another?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`Nokogiri::XML::Node#<<` to append children](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node:%3C%3C):

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'

doc1 = Nokogiri::XML('<doc><foo>Foo</foo></doc>')
doc2 = Nokogiri::XML('<doc><bar>Bar</bar></doc>')
doc3 = Nokogiri::XML('<doc><gah>Gah</gah></doc>')

doc1.root << doc2.root.children # Append doc2's root's children to doc1's root.
doc1.root << doc3.root.children # Append doc3's root's children to doc1's root.

doc1.to_xml # =>
# <doc>
#   <foo>Foo</foo>
#   <bar>Bar</bar>
#   <gah>Gah</gah>
# </doc>
```

Per the docs, you can append any node, document fragment, or node set, so you can select the target nodes in just about any way you want (CSS selectors, XPath, DOM, etc).